# Sorting TObjectList<T> issue within same-comparator-value clusters

Tags: delphi, generics, sorting, tobjectlist

I want to sort `TObjectList<T>` using my own comparer function the comparer function code shown below.

I want from my ObjectList to be able to sort in two direction ascending and descending in order to accomplish this I use SysUtil.CompareText which has two parameters S1 and S2 and to sort in descending way I just opposite the sign of the CompareText result. I don't know if exist another solution everything is fine if s1 greater than S2 or vice versa however if s1 = s2 in the normal case there is no reindex in the list because all elements in the column are identical but the Opposite
happened TObjectList sorted the list as if s1 > s2 or s1 < s2..

My question is how implement a comparer that supports equality and differences?

```
TPerson = class
private
  FName: string;
  FId: string;
public
  property Name: string read FName write FName;
  property ID: string read FID write FID;
end;

TPersons = class(TObjectList<TPerson>)
public
  constructor Create();
  procedure Sort(Direction: string); reintroduce;
end;

procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PersonsList: TPersons;
  I: Integer;
begin
  PersonsList := TPersons.Create;
  PersonsList.Sort('Ascending');
  for I := 0 to PersonsList.Count - 1 do
    ShowMessage(PersonsList[i].Name);
end;

{ TPersons }

constructor TPersons.Create;
var
  Person: TPerson;
begin
  Person := TPerson.Create;
  Person.Name := 'fateh';
  Person.ID := '1';
  Self.Add(Person);

  Person := TPerson.Create;
  Person.Name := 'mohamed';
  Person.ID := '1';
  Self.Add(Person);

  Person := TPerson.Create;
  Person.Name := 'oussama';
  Person.ID := '1';
  Self.Add(Person);
  // all ids are identical
end;

procedure TPersons.Sort(Direction: string);
var
  Comparer   : IComparer<TPerson>;
  Comparison : TComparison<TPerson>;
begin
  if Direction = 'Ascending' then

    Comparison := function(const Person1, Person2 : TPerson): Integer
                  begin
                    result := CompareText(Person1.ID, Person2.ID);
                  end;

  if Direction = 'Descending' then

    Comparison := function(const Person1, Person2 : TPerson): Integer
                  begin
                    result := - CompareText(Person1.ID, Person2.ID);
                  end;

    Comparer := TComparer<TPerson>.Construct(Comparison);

    inherited Sort(Comparer);
end;
```

Comment: As an aside, are you sure "string" is the best choice for the Direction argument?

Comment: no it's not the code is just for illustration ...

Comment: Your comparison function correctly reports that all the items in the list are equal. Why does it matter what order items are in when they're all equal? Maybe the topic you need to go research is *stable sorting*.

Comment: I cannot understand this question. What is your problem?

Comment: i don't have only the id field if tobjectlist sort the id field and it shouldn't that make name field sorted too Arioch 'The explain better than me thank's to all members...

Comment: You still have a unique identifier for each object you can use if the normal comparison result equality `if result = 0 then result := Integer( Person1 ) - Integer( Person2 );`

Comment: @SirRufo that is actually a last resort. In many cases that would enforce persistent but rather random order. If anything, for last try better would be comparing them on "Old-index-in-the-container-before-sorting-started" instead of mere pointer.

Comment: @S.FATEH Just like David, i could not understand your question, though i managed to guess it. Surely you would enhance your English gradually, but as of today - it is almost unintelligible. My advice to you is putting more fixed examples. In this situation you could give three tables: data before sort, data after implemented sort and data after desired sort. And tabular data could easily have dozen of rows, not just three names. There you could demonstrate what happenedand point at the differences. When you cannot find words to explain the ocncept, you at least can find the sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if s1 = s2 in the normal case there is no reindex in the list because all elements in the column are identical

That is wrong idea. Computer should do what you told it - but nothing more.
If you told computer that those objects are equal (in other word, comparator function returned zero) - then the computer is in his right to put them in ANY ORDER that suits his internal sorting implementation.

If you do want some SPECIFIC order among clusters of objects with the same ID - that just means that objects with same ID are NOT REALLY EQUAL, at least not all of those.

Sure, if IDs differ - then objects do as well. But even if those IDs are the same - as long as you care about ordering, that just proves that those objects are still DIFFERENT to You and ID equality is just NOT ENOUGH to specify objects totally equal. And that means You should use nesting, cascading comparator, using more and more finegrain tests until difference spotted.

```
Comparison := function(const Person1, Person2 : TPerson): Integer
  begin
     Result := CompareText(Person1.ID, Person2.ID);
     if Result <> 0 then exit;

     Result := CompareText(Person1.Name, Person2.Name);
     if Result <> 0 then exit;

     Result := Person1.Age - Person2.Age;
     if Result <> 0 then exit;

     Result := GenderCompare(Person1.Sex, Person2.Sex);
     if Result <> 0 then exit;

     Result := Person1.Salary - Person2.Salary;
     if Result <> 0 then exit;

     ...et cetera
  end;
```

Comparing is a kind of mathematics, kind of Algebra. You prove some axioms and then some theories start to work. But only after axioms proving and not more than actual theorem terms.

The very fact that you care about order of objects with the same ID shows that the axiom is false. The comparison is more complex process than ID alone.
You have to make a comparator that would only return zero on truly equal o\bjects, in other words the objects about which respective order you don't care absolutely.

Try reading http://www.howzatt.demon.co.uk/articles/2011-05-equality.html

Comment: @David - i would if i would need it. But actually, just by substituting <old-id, object> instead of mere <object> as a sorting subjects, one can change any algorythm to stable, when it is needed.

Comment: @David, also topic starter wants to use standard Comparator interface and some stock containers. I don't think in this case it is safe to assume anything about sorting algorithm used and its implementation details. Later you would get container from some 3rd party library or different Delphi edition, and sorting algorythm properties may change.